# get specific marker using his coordinates in google maps for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, maps, coordinate

I am using Google Maps in my app for IOS.  I have added several markers in a map and now I need to get a specific one using its coordinates.
I used:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5, -0.127);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
```

but I think I need to create a new marker, not to get one created before.

Comment: marker with position creates a new marker. "Convenience constructor for a default marker" - Google.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have an `NSMutableArray` of the markers and search throughout 
them.

```
for (GMSMarker *marker in arrayOfMarkers){
if(marker.position.latitude == coordinate.latitude && marker.position.longitude == coordinate.longitude){

    return marker;

}
```

NB this assumes that there is only one marker at this location.